# Typed class with generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a method like this:

```
public static void Map<TEntityTrack>()
```

where `TEntityTrack`is a implementation of:

```
public abstract class EntityTrack<TEntity> : EntityTrack, IChangeTrackingService<TEntity>
```

Inside the `Map`method, how could I know the TEntity class type of the TEntityTrack?
I would like to not specify `TEntity` in Map because I want to map my implementations like:

```
TrackMap.Map<MyImplOfTrackByEntity>();
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the type in runtime you can do the following:

```
Type[] genericTypes = typeof(TEntityTrack).GetGenericArguments();
Type entityType = genericTypes[0];
```

adding all the proper bounds-checking etc, of course.

EDIT: In order to find the generic arguments of the base type.

```
Type type = typeof(TEntityTrack);
while (type != typeof(object))
{
    Type[] genericTypes = type.GetGenericArguments();
    if (genericTypes.Length == 0)
    {
        type = type.BaseType;
    }
    else
    {
        Type entityType = genericTypes[0];
        return entityType;
    }
}
// Throw an exception or other appropriate action
throw Exception("Does not have generic argument.");
```

Comment: typeof(TEntityTrack).GetGenericArguments() doesnt return any type.. Any idea?

Comment: Are you passing in a class which derives from a generic class but specifies the generic type? In such a case, you would probably have to traverse the chain of inheritance until the generic type is reached.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a short snippet on how to do that.

Comment: The first snippet didn't work. But with the second one I could get the TEntity! So I guess TEntity is considered as a BaseType in the hierarchy? weird..

Comment: So, `TEntity` is not a base type, but rather the generic argument of the base type. You have a class `A` which inherits a generic class `B<T>`, but specifies the generic parameter: `A : B<string>`. So `A` is not generic, therefore `GetGenericArguments()` returns list of 0. However, the base class of `A`, which is `B<string>` does have a generic argument which is `string`.

Answer (score 5):

You should add a second type parameter on your `Map` method, along with an appropriate [type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public static void Map<TEntityTrack, TEntity>() 
   where TEntityTrack : EntityTrack<TEntity>
{
    var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
}
```

Comment: I got to this before. But if I use this approach I have to specify TEntity in Map, which is what I do not want.

Comment: Hate `var` when you can. It only came in to support LINQ. It makes life easier for the writer and harder for the reader.

Comment: @margabit If you just write `TrackMap.Map<MyImplOfTrackByEntity>();`, the compiler does not have enough information to infer the type of `TEntity`. You have three options: 1) Add a second type parameter as in this example, 2) Pass an instance of `TEntityTrack` as a parameter, 3) Use reflection as in @odyss-jii's answer.

Comment: @dotNET It depends on the context. In this case, the `typeof` operator will only ever return an instance of `Type` -- it should be obvious to the reader what the type of `entityType` will be. In other situations, it might not be so obvious.

Comment: I'll use @odyss-jii's. Thank's a lot!!

Answer (score -1):

If I understood you correctly, you can get the type of the generic parameter using the following statement:

```
Type param = typeof(TEntity);
```

Comment: -1 He wants to know the type of `TEntity`. Please read the question more carefully.